# How to return the Chrome spell-checking menu?

Tags: google-chrome

As you know, in Chrome 49 the spell-checking option in the context menu has disappeared. According to Google they fixed it in Chrome 50. I have a Chrome 51 beta, and I still don't have it.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

1)To enable spell checker click the Chrome menu in the top right corner on the browser window.
2) Select Settings and at the bottom then click Show advanced settings. 
3)Go  to Languages and click the Language and input setting button.
4) In Languages and input settings menu check a box to Enable spell checking as shown in a screen shot
[screen shot to check spell checker checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbjwt.png)

Comment: I already noticed I don't have this option. Here is how it [looks](http://i.imgur.com/jZkvuYg.png). And yes, it is Chrome 51. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Please also try go to chrome menu---settings----click  advance setting--under privacy please check one option "use web service to help resolve spelling errors?"

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Spell Checking menu by going EDIT>SPELLING AND GRAMMAR, see here:[image]